# Angular router link in menu doesn't open new page

Tags: angular, angular-material

In an Angular 5 app, I see an intermittent issue where my menu links (router) do not open the new page. Instead, the page sort of drops out of view. If I scroll down, I can see the same page is a large blank area.

The URL does change to the new page, but the content is not rendered.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```html
<mat-list-item
    sideNavAccordion
    class="sidebar-list-item"
    role="listitem"
    *ngIf="!item.disabled && item.type !== 'separator' && item.type !== 'icon'"
    [ngClass]="{'has-submenu': item.type === 'dropDown'}"
    routerLinkActive="open">
      <a routerLink="/{{item.state}}" *ngIf="item.type === 'link'">
        <span
        class="menu-item-tooltip"
        [matTooltip]="item.tooltip"
        matTooltipPosition="right"></span>
        <mat-icon>{{item.icon}}</mat-icon>
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      </a>

...
```

`app.routes.ts` snippet:

```
<!-- language: lang-ts -->

    export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './views/home/home.module#HomeModule',
        },
        {
            path: '',
            component: AdminLayoutComponent,
            canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'page1',
                    loadChildren: './views/test/test.module#TestModule',
                    data: { title: 'page 1', breadcrumb: 'page1'}
                },
        {
            path: 'page2',
            loadChildren: './views/manage/manage.module#ManageModule',
            data: { title: 'page 2', breadcrumb: 'page2'}
        },
    }
]
```

UPDATE: I believe this is happening when a signed in user's token expires. Menu items that should only appear if the user is authenticated are appearing and they're the ones (I think) that are manifesting the issue. You'd think they'd just work as usual and the AuthGuard would direct the user to the login page, but that's not what seems to be happening. I think if I can get the menu to display correctly, this problem won't occur.

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: Can you provide your router file please ? ?

Comment: @Riscie no, no errors.

Comment: @Toodoo I added app.routes.ts to the question

Comment: Seems like you have one object in the routes array then a series of properties (i.e., the second path isn't enclosed in object notation).

Comment: @rrd  sorry just a typo. I took out some commented out test code and didn’t put back the brackets

Comment: make sure you are importing you routing class in the component level module.

Comment: Are you missing a curly bracket?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './views/home/home.module#HomeModule',
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'page1',
                loadChildren: './views/test/test.module#TestModule',
                data: { title: 'page 1', breadcrumb: 'page1'}
            },
            {
                path: 'page2',
                loadChildren: './views/manage/manage.module#ManageModule',
                data: { title: 'page 2', breadcrumb: 'page2'}
             }]
       }
]
```

there is a typo missing **]** at children in app.routes.ts

Comment: Ya, sorry that was just a typo. My code has the right brackets.